# Hebrew Text in Python

Tags: python

I have a Hebrew text file, and I want to tokenized it by Python 2.7. but there is always problem in encode and decode. Actually I need to tokenize it to construct a **`BagOfWords()`** features ( Get all words that appear more than 100 in all the text, for example ).

So the result is a list of Hebrew words that mostly used.

I tried to decode the text:

```
text = text.decode("cp862")
```

but the output was appeared like:

```
\u2229\u2557\u2510.......
```

I want this file as a list of Hebrew words, not ascii or utf-8 char.

I appreciate your help.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried unicode in front of the string: a=u'\u2229\u2557\u2510'; print a

Comment: You may benefit from [this article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) to understand that there isn't really a thing like a "utf-8 char". The output you are seeing contains the unicode code points for the characters. Your terminal may not be able to display them properly, but that's a different problem.

Comment: It looks like you're decoding a UTF-8 file incorrectly as cp862. Try doing `text = text.decode("utf-8")` instead of `text = text.decode("cp862")` and see if that produces the correct results for you.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon, 
Thank you for your great response. So I am having trouble with my terminal in Linux which I'm using via and SSH server remotely through via code. And it is not displaying the Hebrew characters in The Python file that is generated from a script. Do you have a suggestion how I can enable it to display correctly? Thank you!

Comment: @yishairasowsky There are quite a few things that could be going wrong and it is probably better to ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

If your source text does indeed include a Hebrew text, the *code-page*-based character representation translated into universal UNICODE will allow you to construct the language corpus analytics, the presentation of the <<*word*>> content is not related to the content per-se, but depends on the UI-environment.

As an example here, it is possible to both write and show Hebrew text, as the widget can properly handle the proper contexts ( visual representation of char(s), order of appearance, direction of flow ):

> aSequenceOfCHARs( ALEF, BET, MEM, NUN, AYIN, FINAL PE ) is displayed as:

### אבמנעף

So your main focus -- the language corpus analytics in python -- may work with unicode text-elements independently of their output onto a presentation layer.